# Nonconvex Optimization of inner product objective

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, global-optimization

Does there exist any result on the following minimization,
$$\min_{x\in P} \langle x, F(x)\rangle\equiv \sum_i x_i F_i(x), $$ where $P$ is a convex polytope and $F_i(\cdot)$s are convex functions of $x$. Any related reference is welcome.

Comment: this is a general question . I mean, based on the definition of the Fi(x), this problem can change drastically. it can be a multivariate polynomial function or a simple linear function. can you give more information about the functions Fi?

Comment: I am trying to see under what assumptions there exist results for the above optimization problem. I am interested in vector functions of the form $F(x)= \phi(A^T L(Ax)) $  ($F: \mathbb{R}^p\to\mathbb{R}^p$) and $L(y) = \{\ell_i(y_i)|i=1, \dots, m\} $ ($L: \mathbb{R}^m\to\mathbb{R}^m$). Here $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$, $x\in \mathbb{R}^p$, $y\in \mathbb{R}^m$  and  $\ell_i(\cdot)$ are convex increasing scalar functions.

Comment: $\phi$ is elementwise convex and increasing function, i.e. $\phi: \mathbb{R}^p\to \mathbb{R}^p$ and $\phi_i =\phi()$ (with some abuse of notation). Also $A\in \{0,1\}^{m\times p}$.